# Launching IE in Private Mode in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, selenium-iedriver

I'm trying to run IE 11 in private mode,
browser instance launches IE in normal mode

I have in my registry the key TabProcGrowth REG_DWORD with the value 0 in the required path ../Internet Explorer/Main/

Conf:

node -v 10.7.0
protractor 5.3.2
IE 11
Windows 10

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    "ie.forceCreateProcessApi": true,
    "ie.browserCommandLineSwitches": "-private",
    "ie.ensureCleanSession": true,
},

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
```

or you can try

```
Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "p");
```